# If conditions are not short-circuiting correctly

Tags: java, short-circuiting

I have an `if` condition that evaluates an email address.  I'm testing for 2 things

- It has an "@" sign
- After the first @ sign, it ends with "gmail.com".

My understanding of short-circuiting is that if the first condition in an OR (||) statement is true, then the second won't be evaluated. And yet I'm getting a `NullPointerException` because the second statement does get evaluated (I've tested it).

What don't I understand about short-circuiting here?

The relevant code is below:

FYI: emailtext is from an EditText element and in this case is "notavalidemail"

```
String[] split = emailtext.split("@", 2);
final AlertDialog.Builder notifier = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
Log.i("GetToken","Split[0]=" + split[0] + "; length=" + split.length);

if (split.length == 1 || !split[1].equals("gmail.com")) {
    //Tell the user they didn't enter a correct gmail
}
```

The log in the code returns this:

```
05-02 13:51:16.447  27553-27553/com.farmsoft.lunchguru.app I/GetToken﹕ Split[0]=notavalidemail; length=1
```

Comment: How can it lead to a NullPointerException? If it was really the case with `length=1`, you should get an IndexOutOfBoundsException; but that's not possible, `||` is really short circuiting.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example for us with the input that causes this problem? That way we can run it ourselves (and more importantly: often it helps you find it yourself because you isolate the problem area)

Comment: Well, evidently, `split[1]` is `null`.

Comment: what happens if you remove the not from the statement?  I recall something about not being evaluated before or

Comment: I can't reproduce this.

Comment: How do you know the second statement gets evaluated? I'm tempted to think that since split.length==1 and that you're correct about short-circuiting, that the error comes from some other place. Does the NPE point to that line of code? Do you have a self contained piece of code we can run to reproduce. I bet if you do, you'll have an answer within a minute.

Comment: @user3477950 I also can't reproduce this after copy-pasting the code.  And I left the not operator in there.

Comment: @BobMalooga If split returns 1 element, split[1] will throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: A split on a non-existing character (in your case: `@`) will return an array with 1 element: the entire input string (aka: `.length == 1` will be `true`). So in your example the first condition is *always* `true` with that input. However when it tries to access `split[1]` you're going out of the bounds of your array and thus it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, as others have noted before. Therefore the problem is not in the code you have shown us (once again: isolate it!).

Comment: What version of Java and which jvm and version?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to avoid the problem :

```
    String[] split = emailtext.split("@", 2);

    final AlertDialog.Builder notifier = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Log.i("GetToken","Split[0]=" + split[0] + "; length=" + split.length);

    boolean errorMail = true;
    if(split.length == 2)
    {
        if(split[1].equals("gmail.com"))
        {
            errorMail = false;
        }
    }
    if(errorMail)
    {
        // Mail error
    }
```